# Type: array of keys of a particular interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface:

```
interface ParentProps {
   one: number;
   two: string;
   three: string;
}
```

A Parent React.Component, whose props are specified by the interface and that passes ['one', 'two', 'three'] to a Child.

```
   class Parent extends React.Component<ParentProps> {
...
   return (
       <Child keys={Object.keys(this.props)}>Hello</Child>
   )
...
```

This is an excerpt of Child's code:

```
...
   return this.props.keys.map(v => <div>v</div>)
...
```

**Question:** How can I specify that this.props.keys should be of type `array of keys of ParentProps`, which in this case is `['one', 'two', 'three']`so that if I add a forth prop to ParentProps (i.e. { four: number }), it would appear on ChildProps automatically?

This is what I tried:

1) gives keys of array.prototype:

```
interface ChildProps {
     keys: keyof ParentProps[];
}
```

2) gives an array of one of Parent Props:

```
interface ChildProps {
     keys: [keyof ParentProps];
}
```

3) gives this: ("one" | "two" | "three")[]

```
interface ChildProps {
    keys: (keyof ParentProps)[];
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: What is wrong with `("one" | "two" | "three")[]`?  That's exactly "array of keys of `ParentProps`".

Comment: @jcalz This is what I get:
`Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("one" | "two" | "three")[]'.`
I suppose the problem is with `Object.keys`. Since if I just pass array of hardcoded keys from parent to child, it works.

Comment: Yes, [`Object.keys`’s signature says it returns `string[]`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L261).

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, typescript does not recognize keys of this.props, which is wrapped by Object.keys and infers type of value that we pass to a child as `string[]`. Passing props this way solves the problem:

```
class Parent extends React.Component<ParentProps> {
...
   return (
       <Child keys={Object.keys(this.props) as (keys ParentProps)[]}>Hello</Child>
   )
...
```